# How to get around dynamic elements when web-scraping?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jquery-selectors

The code below works as I am able to click a button on the webpage using Python/Selenium/Firefox.

[button on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwdS5.png)

```
driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('dba-app').shadowRoot.getElementById('configRenderer').shadowRoot.querySelector('ing-default-layout-14579').querySelector('dba-overview').shadowRoot.querySelector('ing-feat-agreement-overview').shadowRoot.querySelector('ing-ow-overflow-menu-14587').shadowRoot.querySelector('button')''').click()
```

However, some elements are dynamic and the numbers are changing anytime you rerun the script.

The changing elements:

- 'ing-default-layout-**14579**'
- 'ing-ow-overflow-menu-**14587**'

What must I do to get around the dynamic elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to look for other attributes that stay the same across pageloads. For example, given your HTML, you could do:

```
document.querySelector('#configRenderer') // returns the config renderer element
document.querySelector('[data-tag-name="ing-default-layout"]') // returns the ing-default-layout element
document.querySelector('[data-tag-name="dba-overview]') // returns the dba-overview element
```

And so on. Or you could the same method to identify a parent or a child, and then navigate to the child or parent respectively.

If the HTML isn't stable enough even for that, another approach would be to search through *all* elements, and find the one(s) whose `tagName` starts with what you need.

```
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
  if (elm.tagName.toLowerCase().startsWith('ing-ow-overflow-menu')) {
    // do stuff with elm, which is the overflow menu element
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution had a typo but after that it worked like a charm, thanks! I had actually tried something similar and should've continued trying. Anyhow, works now!